# Automatically move cell reference over: How can I do this in Excel without manually updating the formula each week?

Tags: excel, function

I have a sales tracker spreadsheet and am trying to figure out how to create a formula where each week's sales is multiplied by the retail. However; the cell reference would need to move over by 1 cell each week.  For example: `BN=AE4*F4` where `AE4` is last week's sales and `F4` is the retail of the item. When I update the report for next week, I would like for the formula to read as `BN=AF4*F4`.  How can I do this in Excel without manually updating the formula each week?

Comment: Is the 'last week sales' figure always the right-most number of the row?

Comment: Please provide more information about how your spreadsheet is set up (header locations, where data is input, where data is output, does it only show for a year and then you have a new file, etc etc). A simple response will likely be to have a header row which has the first day of each week on row 1, and then an index / match combination to pull that week's info.

Comment: This looks like a more appropriate question for superuser

Comment: Header Row is Row 3; Columns G:BG are all the quantities sold, by week. Column F; Row 4 is the retail of the item and does not vary week to week. Row 4 is the data for 2015. Row 5 is for 2014, Row 6 is the % Change. So far, I have the data for each week starting on 2/7/15 and ending on 7/25/15. The "Most Recent Week's Sales $" is in cell BN4 which is just the last week's quantity sold (in AE4) multiplied by the retail (in F4). I want to have Excel re-calculate the formula in cell BN4 to be BN4=AF4*F4 (last week's Sales $ for week of 8/1/15) multiplied by the retail (F4).  Can Excel do this?

Answer (score 1):

To multiply F4 by whatever is the last number (reading left-to-right) in row 4 use this formula.

```
=F4*INDEX(4:4, MATCH(1E+99, 4:4))
```

Comment: There in lies the problem. I have hidden columns from AE:BG. These columns all have formulas which is just a vlookup off of another spreadsheet. I have a formula in BI4 that calculates the sum of only the visible columns. Can Excel pull the latest visible week's data (which would be AF4 next week) and multiply by the Retail in F4 without me having to manually change the reference in the formula to be BN4=AF4*F4?